# Change partitions in Visual Studio command prompt

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

In the MSDOS command prompt to change to a different partition, you just type

```
C:\> cd E:
```

But this doesn't work in visual studio. How do I change to another drive/partition in Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use the drive name directly, calling `CD` is not required:

```
C:\> E:
```

This works in normal MSDOS.

Comment: Make sure to leave off the backslash after E: struggled with this for a while :)

Comment: Do you know why this is?

Comment: @conighion - because changing a drive is not the same as changing a directory, I assume. Probably a design decision.